# Scroll View causing hamburger icon to not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview, navigation-drawer

So I'm using a modified version of the default Navigation Drawer template provided by Android Studio. The Toolbar has an icon in the top left that opens the Navigation Drawer and it works in most fragments. However, the icon is not working when I move to one of the fragments in my activity. This is one of the few fragments that has a scroll view, and I've seen that removing the scroll view allows the button to work again.

Does anyone know how I can keep the scroll view while still getting the button to work?

The layout file for the problem fragment (The context name is omitted):

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/topmargin"
    tools:context="com.example....FAQFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/faqLayout"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textSideMargin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/textSideMargin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/textSideMargin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/sidebarcontent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment code:

```
public class FAQFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<String> questions;
    private ArrayList<String> answers;
    private int currentlyVisible = -1;

    public FAQFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FAQFragment newInstance() {
        FAQFragment fragment = new FAQFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //todo: figure out why the scroll view is causing the tool bar to not work
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.faqHeader));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_faq, container, false);
        LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.faqLayout);
        readQuestionFile();
        for(int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv.setTag(i);
            tv.setText(questions.get(i));
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.bottomMargin = 5;
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setTextSize(16);
            tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.mainColor));
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clicked(view);
                }
            });
            mainView.addView(tv);

            TextView tv2 = new TextView(getActivity());
            tv2.setTag("answer");
            tv2.setText(answers.get(i));
            tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv2.setTextSize(16);
            tv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mainView.addView(tv2);
        }

        TextView copyright = new TextView(getActivity());
        copyright.setTextSize(14);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        copyright.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        copyright.setLayoutParams(params);
        copyright.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        copyright.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.mainColor));
        copyright.setText("\n" + getString(R.string.copyright));
        mainView.addView(copyright);

        //todo: all the numbers here (text size) should refer to dimens.xml
        return view;
    }
```

Fragment Transaction:

```
   private void changeFrag(Fragment f) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        currentFrag = f;
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, currentFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's not enough information to diagnose your problem. Please [edit] your question to include the main layout XML, and the code for the `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: ok I added all of those

Comment: Your `DrawerLayout` should have only one main content `View`. That is, put your `navbar` `<include>` and `FrameLayout` in another `ViewGroup`; e.g., a vertical `LinearLayout`. As you have it now, the `FrameLayout` is on top of the `navbar`.